# Refresh the content when the buttons are pressed in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a form which contains 2 buttons , a datetimepicker and datagridview which binds to a table in the database.My question is: How can i refresh the datagridview displayed data every time i press a different button or when i switch the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reset your datasource in datagridview control and reasign it again to new datatable or dataset
when you click button or when you change data in your datatimepicker control

```
void UpdateCustomersDGV()
{
    DataTable dtCustomers = dataAccessLayer.GetCustomers();
    dgcCustomers.DataSource = null;
    dgvCustomers.DataMember ="";
    dgvCustomers.DataSource = dtCustomers;
}
```

call this function on button click event

Comment: Could you give me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this as my answer:

At the beginning of

```
        DataGridView.Rows.Clear();
```